# Tags 'stubs', 'ms-shims' and 'microsoft-fakes': Oh my

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There seems to be a bit of confusion regarding the tags [stubs](/questions/tagged/stubs) and [ms-shims](/questions/tagged/ms-shims). Despite the fact that [the wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stubs/info) for [stubs](/questions/tagged/stubs) states that it applies specifically to the *[Microsoft Fakes framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx)*, many other questions are getting the [stubs](/questions/tagged/stubs) tag for different implementations of stubbing.

1. Should the [stubs](/questions/tagged/stubs) and [ms-shims](/questions/tagged/ms-shims) tags should be folded into the [microsoft-fakes](/questions/tagged/microsoft-fakes) tag?
2. Should `stubs` be split into a generic [stubs](/questions/tagged/stubs) and a child [ms-stubs](/questions/tagged/ms-stubs) tag?

I originally tried to remove all the [ms-shims](/questions/tagged/ms-shims) questions, but then I saw that [stubs](/questions/tagged/stubs) had 32 questions. This isn't huge, but I thought it was worth discussing.

Comment: stubs seems too generic to dedicate to a Microsoft specific tool. The wiki says that, but that isn't how it's being used. It can be used for a variety of reasons, such as stubs in a mocking framework ([like this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891967/understanding-stubs-fakes-and-mocks)). I would get rid of the stubs tag by hand reviewing, either replacing the tag with [microsoft-fakes] or if it isn't related to that framework at all, getting rid of the tag all together (or finding a suitable replacement).

Comment: I fixed the stubs tag wiki.